# How to import objects from My Maps to Google Places

Tags: google-maps

We have a map with hundreds of points but they don't appear in Google Maps search. I was told that if I put them in Google Places, they will appear in maps search.

Is this true?

And if it is true how can I transfer them painless from Maps to Places?

Answer (score 1):

You go to Google Maps and Select *My Places* from the *Settings* in the lower right corner, then click *Create map*, and then *Create a new map*, you will see *Import* (import data from CSV file or spreadcheet).

By clicking *Import*, you can upload a CSV file from your computer.

I already tested this, but have no idea how to convert your maps into that CSV file in the first place. There is an option called *Export to KML file* when you click the folder icon in *Create a new map* (after creating the map), are those file types the same? Look at the text below from http://EzineArticles.com/5651522.

The file extension KML stores geographic modeling information in an XML format. This information includes lines, polygons, points and image and is used for identifying and labeling overlay textures, locations. These files with KML extension were used originally by a Keyhole mapping software created by Keyhole Incorporated. This company was taken over by Google in 2004. As a result of this acquisition, KML files are now utilized by Google Earth....

The difference between the two types is that CSV files are similar to text ones with the text being more organized while KML is used for storing geographic modeling information.

Comment: KML and CSV are not compatible. [KML is an XML dialect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KML), while [CSV is simply a list of comma-separated values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

Comment: I know that, that is why I wonder why Google are asking  in Import for a file that they don't actually export to!!.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if they [qualify for Google Places](http://www.google.com/support/places/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=107528). Google Places is just for business locations, to be added by business owners. If you aren't the owner of the business, you don't qualify. If you do qualify, there's a [bulk import option](http://www.google.com/support/places/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=28247&topic=28291&answer=178024).

Depending on the region, if these are points of interest, you may be able to add the locations via [Map Maker](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157176). Though, I don't know if they allow a bulk import option.